# What can I do to see all the contents of my page when screens are smaller

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap. What can I do to see all the contents of my page when screens are smaller. My table in Activities panel doesn't adjust with the screen size.I have a div named MiddleDiv where I append 1 or more tables on the fly.

```
    <div class="container">

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
         <div class="panel-heading">Activities</div>
         <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive" id="MiddleDiv">
               <table width="100%" style="margin-bottom:10px" id="Table_1" class="TableBlankClass table">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr class="bg-success">
                        <td style="font-weight:bold" id="ActivityCompany_1" colspan="3">Company(Bill to): TD General Insurance Company</td>
                        <td style="font-weight:bold" id="ActivityClient_1" colspan="6">Client: Test Adjsuter</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                           <table width="100%">
                              <tbody>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="ActivityDel_1" onclick="DelActivity('Table_1')" type="button">Del</button></td>
                                    <td class="ActivitiesHeading">Activity</td>
                                    <td>
                                       <select onchange="GetRate('Table_1')" id="ActivityTypeDropDown_1" style="width:200px;" class="form-control TableSelectClass">
                                          <option value="- Select One -" selected="">- Select One -</option>
                                          <option value="Accomodation">Accomodation</option>

                                       </select>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                              </tbody>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                        <td class="ActivitiesHeading">Comments</td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="ActivitiesHeading"><textarea rows="1" style="width: 275px; height: 35px;" class="form-control" id="ActivityComments_1"></textarea></td>
                        <td class="ActivitiesHeading">Status<span id="ActivitySpan_1"></span></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="ActivitiesHeading">
                           <select onchange="CalculateActivities(); CreateRemoveReasonButton('Table_1');" id="ActivityStatusDropDown_1" style="width:200px;" class="form-control">
                              <option value="24859" selected="">Waiting To Process Payer Invoice</option>

                           </select>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="ActivitiesHeading">Rate</td>
                        <td class="ActivitiesHeading">Qty</td>
                        <td class="ActivitiesHeading">Discount</td>
                        <td class="ActivitiesHeading">Discount %</td>
                        <td class="ActivitiesHeading">Reason For Discount</td>
                        <td class="ActivitiesHeading">Tax Applicable</td>
                        <td class="ActivitiesHeading">Taxes</td>
                        <td class="ActivitiesHeading">SubTotal</td>
                        <td class="ActivitiesHeading">Gross Total</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" onblur="if (this.value=='') {this.value = 0;}" value="0" onkeyup="CalculateActivities()" id="ActivityRate_1" class="form-control TableNumericClass"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" onblur="if (this.value=='' || this.value=='0') {this.value = 1;}" value="1" onkeyup="CalculateActivities()" id="ActivityQty_1" class="form-control TableNumericClass"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" onblur="if (this.value=='0') {this.value = '';}" value="" onkeyup="CalculateActivities()" id="ActivityDiscount_1" class="form-control TableDiscountClass"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" onblur="if (this.value=='0') {this.value = '';}" value="" onkeyup="CalculateActivities()" id="ActivityDiscountPercentage_1" class="form-control TableDiscountClass"></td>
                        <td>
                           <select id="ReasonForDiscountDropDown_1" class="form-control">
                              <option value="- Select One -" selected="">- Select One -</option>
                              <option value="Late Report Delivery">Late Report Delivery</option>
                              <option value="Incorrect File Management">Incorrect File Management</option>
                              <option value="Client Satisfaction">Client Satisfaction</option>
                              <option value="Other - See Service Notes">Other - See Service Notes</option>
                           </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <select onchange="CalculateActivities()" id="ActivityTaxApplicable_1" class="form-control">
                              <option value="Yes" selected="">Yes</option>
                              <option value="No">No</option>
                           </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><img width="15" height="15" title="&lt;body&gt; &lt;table width=&quot;150px&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;1&quot; cellpadding=&quot;1&quot;&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td class=&quot;ToolTipTableClass&quot;&gt;Tax1 :&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td class=&quot;ToolTipTableClass&quot;&gt;0.00&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td class=&quot;ToolTipTableClass&quot;&gt;Tax2 :&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td class=&quot;ToolTipTableClass&quot; &gt;0.00&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt; &lt;/table&gt; &lt;/body&gt;" src="/files/404048/93171/Info-32.png" id="ActivityTaxesAmount_1" class="TaxesClass" data-original-title="&lt;body&gt; &lt;table width=&quot;150px&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;1&quot; cellpadding=&quot;1&quot;&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td class=&quot;ToolTipTableClass&quot;&gt;Tax1 :&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td class=&quot;ToolTipTableClass&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td class=&quot;ToolTipTableClass&quot;&gt;Tax2 :&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td class=&quot;ToolTipTableClass&quot; &gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt; &lt;/table&gt; &lt;/body&gt;"></td>
                        <td id="ActivitySubTotal_1">100.00</td>
                        <td id="ActivityGrossTotal_1">100.00</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="ActivitiesHeading">Measure</td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="ActivitiesHeading">GAP Code</td>
                        <td colspan="3" class="ActivitiesHeading">Other Description</td>
                        <td colspan="3" class="ActivitiesHeading">&nbsp;</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                           <select id="ActivityMeasure_1" class="form-control">
                              <option selected="" value="- Select One -">- Select One -</option>

                           </select>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                           <select id="ActivityGAPCode_1" class="form-control">
                              <option value="00000" selected="">&lt;-Select One-&gt;</option>

                           </select>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="ActivityOtherDescription_1" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td colspan="3">

                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
         <div class="panel-heading">Total</div>
         <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
               <table width="100%" class="table">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="HeadingTD">SubTotal</td>
                        <td id="AllSubTotal"></td>
                        <td class="HeadingTD">Discount</td>
                        <td id="AllDiscount"></td>
                        <td class="HeadingTD">Tax</td>
                        <td id="AllTax"></td>
                        <td class="HeadingTD">Gross Total</td>
                        <td id="AllGrossTotal"></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" id="AddItemTD"></td>
                        <td colspan="2" id="SubmitActivitiesTD"></td>
                        <td colspan="2" id="VoidInvoiceTD"></td>
                        <td colspan="2" align="right"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="window.parent.close()" type="button">Close</button></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There no link but you can reduce `col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-12`  by `col-xs-12`

Comment: You're mixing bootstrap and non-bootstrap classes, and inline style attributes. You should include your custom classes to help people troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Here is bootply to work on : http://www.bootply.com/YLVfPak7tb

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are just wrapping traditional HTML tables with some bootstrap classes expecting them to be responsive.

It's a good start but you need to rethink how you construct your tables when you use bootstrap.

Bootstrap uses their "Grid System" http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

The grid system doesn't use tables at all. It uses divs with specific classes on them achieve the layout you are looking for. Until you fully use the bootstrap grid system you will not truly see a responsive design.

Take the time to learn the bootstrap grid system.

**A bit of a side note and personal opinion:**  Looking at your form design (which looks great btw) you might not like the result of a responsive design. All of the form fields will end up stacking on top of each other. This form design really only works horizontally. If it were vertically aligned it might get very confusing. If it were me, I might design the form to fit interfaces as small as a tablet but not mobile.

Comment: Thank you very much. Any suggestions where can I keep HTML tables structure and it is responsive as well?